# Trouble with basic JavaScript game

Tags: javascript

I want to change this hangman game I made so that instead of doing a random word each time I press new game, it does the words in the exact order they are in.

```
    // constants
    var POSSIBLE_WORDS = ["first", "second", "third"];
    var MAX_GUESSES = 7; // number of total guesses per game

    // global variables
    var word = "?"; // random word user is trying to guess
    var guesses = ""; // letters the player has guessed
    var guessCount = MAX_GUESSES; // number of guesses player has left
    var borderColor = 60;

    // Chooses a new random word and displays its clue on the page.
    function newGame() {
// choose a random word
    var randomIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * POSSIBLE_WORDS.length);
    word = POSSIBLE_WORDS[randomIndex];
    guessCount = MAX_GUESSES;
    guesses = "";
    borderColor = 60;
    document.getElementById("hangmanpic").style.border = "thin none hsla(0,0%,100%,1)";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundColor = "hsla(0,0%,100%,1)";
    updatePage(); // show initial word clue - all underscores
        }
```

Comment: Is there a question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Do some debugging. We're not going to go through a wall of code for you. Ask a specific question about a specific line of code and tell us what you tried.

Comment: Instead of picking a random number, use a counter variable. Increment it each turn.

Answer (score 1):

First, set a counter variable:

```
var LAST_INDEX=0;
```

Next, at the top of `newGame()` function, instead of choosing a random index, choose `LAST_INDEX` and then increment `LAST_INDEX` by 1.

```
word=POSSIBLE_WORDS[LAST_INDEX];
++LAST_INDEX;
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable to hold the index of the current word:

```
var currIndex = 0;
```

And then in `newGame` increment the counter instead of generating a random number:

```
word = POSSIBLE_WORDS[currIndex];

currIndex = (currIndex + 1) % POSSIBLE_WORDS.length;   // for the next round
```

This will rotate through the words in order.

If you don't want to rotate, then remove the mod part (`%`) and just increment `currIndex` and check for the end of the list by comparing with `POSSIBLE_WORDS.length`